# Setting minSdkVersion does not work in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a brand new project I started via the new project wizard where I am experimenting with material and the Android L SDK. I have my emulator set to sdk L where my actual device is running SDK 19. I tried creating separate "productFlavors" a "modern" one for "L" and an "old" one for 19 and finally using the "old" one to run on device but that didn't work. I finally tried removing all traces of SDK "L" from my build.gradle and even went as far as setting the min/target version to 19 in the AndroidManifest.xml but when I try to run it the device chooser still somehow picks up that "L" is the minSDK.

[image: screenshot of device chooser]

I've sync'ed and resync'ed my gradle build files, I've run clean prior to running the run config, I've even looked through the properties files to see if there was a target set somewhere that I missed. It seems that by merely using the "L" SDK the minimunTarget gets fixed to "L" which I don't believe is right. Where am I going wrong?

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.craig.mymaterial'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        modern {
//            minSdkVersion 'L'
//            targetSdkVersion 'L'
        }
        old {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.craig.mymaterial" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_item_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".ItemListActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ItemListActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Material Design will not be officially supported until the Android L release, Google has made it so that anything compiled with "Android-L" is locked to that version.

There may be a work around, but the "official" solution would be changing your compile version to take care of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I just found this answer which thoroughly explains the situation as well as a work around: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/

Answer (score 0):

Your compile version is 20 but the version you have set up in the emulator is 19. If you set the compileSdkVersion to 19, it should run

Comment: Yup, it seems that "L" preview is just that, a preview. It won't be backward compatible until it is officially released. Setting my compile SDK to 19 or 20 does not allow me to use the Material theme.

Comment: Then you cant use it on a device/emulator running SDK 19